# How to consider geographical location when selecting hosting provider?

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting, shared-hosting, cloud-hosting

I am going to buy a hosting service (re seller) where mostly people from Ethiopia will be using it. I am going to host my applications in this server and also partition and sell for other developers to host their apps. So I am not sure, if I have to host my application in the US, UK, AU or somewhere else. Does selecting a hosting service that is located in either one of the above places would affect the reliability of the service for the users from that specific country? (The data is not sensitive ) My main aim is, to make sure that the server is reliable all the time (99.9%) for the users from that country.

Answer (score 1):

If our order CDN technology together with hosting, you won't have to pay attention to the geographical location of your servers.

A content delivery network (CDN) is a group of servers, located in different countries and  connected to a single network. The system is configured in the following way: your site visitors are granted access to the  site data copy from the server which is the nearest to them. With CDN your site pictures, text, files, audio and video streaming media will be loading  quicker for the users from different places and the server load on the main server will be decreased.

CDN benefits
•   Rapid site loading speed from any place of the world
•   Server overload decrease on the main server 
•   a lot of servers( at least 40-50) all over the world keep your site contents
•   SEO positions escalation in search engines 
•   Suitable for all popular CMS systems

Nowadays,[Fastnext](http://fastnext.com/) company offer CDN for free.

Answer (score 0):

All those countries have perfectly reliable hosting companies. Blue Host, HostMonster, 1and1 are some of the largest in the world and will do fine no matter where you live.

Though they all don't offer reseller accounts which let you setup your own plans.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Ok, that might be fine for posting our web app. But, we are going to build different systems and we might not afford buying new plan every time plus we want to go in to the reselling business as well. So, any recommendations or links you can provide to me. I know most companies from Ethiopia host in UK. I have no idea why.

Comment: If you're building your own apps you should have root access to the server, that means you'll need either a dedicated, VPS, or cloud server. Hostgator.com has reseller plans.

Comment: Yes we are building our own apps as well ass hosting other developers' apps. I have seen Hostgator.com and seems interesting. One thing I am worried about is graphical location. You can look at  the answer below, if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If there are reliable providers on Africa, I would recommend you to register with them. It's good for SEO.

Or you can find other providers from Europe, Africa near with Europe, so I can recommend you can find provider in Europe. You can try hostforlife.eu and asphostdirectory.com. I find their site on Microsoft and I see that this provider has many good reviews. Good luck. :)

Comment: Well. Nothing I know of in Africa. Though, most of companies in Ethiopia post their apps in UK and some of them in US. But why Europe?

Comment: IP addresses have nothing to do with SEO

Comment: In my opinion, Europe near with Africa, so it will makes your site load faster. :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should go for cloud hosting maybe [Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/)  Europe data center. 99.9% uptime and you could sell with more benefit. I'd have to say don't go with shared hosting.